# Sending email with PHP, Gmail doesn't work

Tags: php, html, email, gmail

When I try to send my mail via php, `GMail` does not accept my `html`:

Simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>

<body style="padding:0px; margin:0PX;" bgcolor="#dfdfdf">
<table width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor=""  style="table-layout:fixed; margin:0 auto;">
<tr>
<td width="640" align="center" valign="top">

  Screenshot: <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,someimginfo" />

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

GMail output:

[image]

Gmail edits my text e.g. `<html>` --> `"<html>"`

The headers I use: `MIME-Version: 1.0` & `Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** `PHP` Code:

```
<?php
$recipient = "xxxxxx@gmail.com";

$image = $_POST["image"];
$contact = $_POST["contact"];
$token = $_POST["token"];

if($token != "***"){
  exit('{"success":false, "error":"Invalid Token"}');
}

$from = (filter_var($contact, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) ? $contact : 'no- reply@example.com';
$header = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

$txt = '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>

<body style="padding:0px; margin:0PX;" bgcolor="#dfdfdf">
<table width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor=""  style="table-layout:fixed; margin:0 auto;">
<tr>
<td width="640" align="center" valign="top">

  Screenshot: <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $image . '" />

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
';

if(mail($recipient, "APP Support request", $txt, $header)){
  exit('{"success":true}');
}

exit('{"success":false, "image":"' . $image . '"}');
?>
```

Comment: Can you post the PHP code you use to set those headers and send the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPmailer is the best class for the job!
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Edit: replaced http://phpmailer.worxware.com/ with the github address.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is in these lines:

```php
$header = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

// …

if(mail($recipient, "APP Support request", $txt, $header)){
```

You switch between the names `$header` and `$headers`. So when you add the `text/html` content type to the variable `$headers`, that isn’t affecting the `$header` variable that is being used to actually send the email.

You should switch all those variables to the same name, `$headers`.